# What are the best ways to generate Bayesian prior estimates using beliefs of non-statisticians?

Tags: bayesian, prior

I work with a lot of qualitative researchers and designers. Many of whom interact with users and develop strong, often accurate intuitions about how the data should look. I frequently try to quantify their intuitions so that we can integrate their beliefs with new data.

Asking the right question is tough and the way I ask the question changes what the priors look like. I have a few different methods (mostly for proportions):

- make wagers on the probability of different hypotheses and then turn that into Bayes factor
- how many people out of X would do Y?
- I go reverse and ask people what their posterior beliefs are
  following running into fake new data (you can estimate their prior
  from that)

Clearly this isn't an academic exercise, but one to create engagement over new data.

**What questions would you ask someone who doesn't know much about stats to accurately quantify their beliefs into a Bayesian prior and how do you go from their answer to a prior (R code would be nice)?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a good question.  I'm going to use a simple example to illustrate my approach.

Suppose I am working with someone who needs to provide me priors on the mean and the variance for a gaussian likelihood.  Something like

$$ y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2) $$

The question is: "What are this person's priors on $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$?"

For the mean I might ask "Gimme a range on what you think the expected value might be".  They might say "between 20 and 30".  I'm free to then interpret that as I may (perhaps as the IQR of the prior on $\mu$).

Now, I'll use R (or more likely Stan) to simulate possible scenarios in order to further narrow down what a realistic prior is.  So for example, my colleague says $\mu$ is between 20 and 30.  Now I have to decide on a prior for $\sigma$.  So, I may show them the following and say "which of these four looks more realistic and why?"

[image]

They might say "the first is much to variable, and the last two are much to precise. The second looks more realistic, but it is too concentrated at 25!"

At this time, I'll go back and adjust the priors for the mean while narrowing in on a prior for the variance.

This is called a "prior predictive check" -- essentially sampling from the prior to make sure that the priors are actually reflective of what the state of the knowledge is.  The process can be slow, but if your collaborators have no data or statistical expertise, then what can they expect of you?  Not every parameter can be given a flat prior.

Stan code used to generate samples:

```
data{

  real mu_mean;
  real mu_sigma;

  real sigma_alpha;
  real sigma_beta;

}
generated quantities{

  real mu = normal_rng(mu_mean, mu_sigma);
  real sigma = gamma_rng(sigma_alpha, sigma_beta);
  real y = normal_rng(mu, sigma);
}
```

R code used to generate figures

```
library(rstan)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

make_plot = function(x){

fit1 = sampling(scode, data = x, algorithm = 'Fixed_param', iter = 10000, chains =1 )

t1 = tibble(y = extract(fit1)$y)

p1 = t1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y))+
  geom_histogram()+
  xlim(0,50)

return(p1)
}
d1 = list(mu_mean = 25, mu_sigma = 1, sigma_alpha = 5, sigma_beta = 1)
d2 = list(mu_mean = 25, mu_sigma = 1, sigma_alpha = 3, sigma_beta = 1)
d3 = list(mu_mean = 25, mu_sigma = 1, sigma_alpha = 1, sigma_beta = 1)
d4 = list(mu_mean = 25, mu_sigma = 1, sigma_alpha = .1, sigma_beta = 2)
d = list(d1, d2, d3, d4)

y = map(d, make_plot) 

reduce(y,`+`)
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you prefer to generate the data in Stan rather than R?

Comment: @James I'm probably going to fit the Bayesian model in Stan.  Writing the data generating process in Stan helps me solidify the model structure in my mind.  Also, there are differences in parameterizations between software, so playing in one sandbox is a bit safer (so to speak).

Comment: Hm, this is my first exposure to Stan - at first, I thought you had a guy named Stan running your probabilistic simulations for you!

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks. How much variance in their answers do you think that you would get based on slight, seemingly irrelevant changes in the way you talk to people about this? Also, if people gave you a range, could you estimate the mean and the variance (with some assumptions about what that range represents)? For example, if we ran 10000 studies, what would be a surprisingly low mean (less than 5% of studies would be lower)? What would be a surprisingly high mean (less than 5% would be higher)? I'm being greedy --- thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @DerekDeBellis Those all sound like fine approaches.  There are no right answers here, you just have to justify your approach and be very precise in what you say to who.  Leave no room for ambiguity.

Comment: I wonder whether this should be asked as a separate question, but when working with non-statisticians, is there a crystal-clear way to get them to distinguish between when you want to know about the "spread of the possible/plausible values of $\mu_X$" versus the "spread of the possible/plausible values of $X$"? I can't be the only person who's found non-technical people can sometimes struggle to distinguish between the two concepts...

Comment: @Silverfish "Crystal-clear"  will depend highly on who is giving and receiving the explanation.  I always default to the "imagine conducting the experiment again and again..." though I don't think that is as effective as I want it to be, especially since this is the motivation behind the definition of the confidence interval and people get that wrong all the time.